# List inside Java XML Properties

Tags: java, xml, properties, dtd

I want to store a list of key-value pairs as values to specific key in a properties xml file.

Consider following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="led.color">
       <color key="r">0</color>
       <color key="g">100</color>
       <color key="b">0</color>
    </entry>
</properties>
```

My initial approach was to retrieve the value of `led.color` as String and convert it to a Map. But the retrieval failed with following exception:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 20; Element type "color" must be declared.

This happens because color is not declared in the DTD and hence, the validation fails.

Is there any build-in way to handle such task or a way to avoid the validation of this specific value?

This is the references DTD:

```
<!--
   Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
-->
<!-- DTD for properties -->
<!ELEMENT properties ( comment?, entry* ) >
<!ATTLIST properties version CDATA #FIXED "1.0">
<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT entry (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST entry key CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: you can build your custom DTD or XSD

Comment: Do you know any references for that?

Comment: Hmm. Google? "how to write DTD"?

Comment: you should use xml schema instead of dtd

Comment: @BastianSchoettle http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp

Comment: <!--
   Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
  -->

<!-- DTD for properties -->

<!ELEMENT properties ( comment?, entry* ) >

<!ATTLIST properties version CDATA #FIXED "1.0">

<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT entry (#PCDATA) >

<!ATTLIST entry key CDATA #REQUIRED>

Any ideas how to exclude "color" from the validation?

Comment: The whole point of a DTD or schema is to guarantee a specific structure.  If you want to have custom elements, you must use a custom schema or DTD.  Of course, you can easily store a color in a properties file as its ARGB notation, then read it in your code with `Color.decode(properties.getProperty("led.color"))`.  The format is described by [Integer.decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

your new xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "properties.dtd">
 <properties>
   <entry key="led.color">
    <color key="r">0</color>
    <color key="g">100</color>
    <color key="b">0</color>
  </entry>
</properties>
```

properties.dtd file to put in the same directory

```
 <?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!ELEMENT properties (entry)>
 <!ATTLIST properties xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

 <!ELEMENT entry (color)+>
 <!ATTLIST entry xmlns CDATA #FIXED '' key NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>

 <!ELEMENT color (#PCDATA)>
 <!ATTLIST color xmlns CDATA #FIXED '' key NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
```